# Anyone know how I can just use one JOptionPane.showMessageDialog for the switch cases?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
int dogs;
dogs = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many dogs do you have?"));
switch (dogs)
 {
  case 0: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You really should get a dog. They're great pets."); break;
  case 1: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Glad you have a dog."); break;
  case 2: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Two dogs are better than one."); break;
  case 3: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Three dogs is a lot."); break;
  case 4: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Four dogs is too many."); break;
  case 5: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Five dogs means you're a crazy person."); break;
  case 6: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is totally unbelieveable."); break;
  default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input.");
 } // end switch
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 4):

Use an array.

```
String[] messages = {
  "You really should get a dog...",
  ...
};
```

Of course you will need to check the bounds of the array

```
if (dogs > 0 && dogs < messages.length) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, messages[dogs]);
}
```

Read: [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: This is something that waaaay too many programmers forget waaaay too often. It would be helpful if you could show how to initialize the array as well, since Danny might not know that.

Comment: Very good, +1 :) Now let's hope that no code he ever writes will end up at www.codecrap.com

Comment: Is it possible to initialize a variable then set that variable equal to all the messages and have one JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,'variable goes here') then depending on what the user enters the output will be one of the messages? This is for a class I'm taking and we haven't gone over arrays yet, so I don't think my professor will allow us to use it.

Comment: That what arrays are for. Follow the example, read the doc and you will impress the socks off your professor